# Highlight matched expression EXCEPT whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an Ajaxsearch (like Google) where you type a word, and autocomplete forms in the bottom, and matching keyword gets highlighted. The problem is whitespace is also being highlighted (being given strong tag) and this increases the width of whitespace.

I have to modify the following function, but I just have no clue what this does.

```
highlight: function(value, term) {
    return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
},
```

Comment: There are plenty of problems with your current code. It also seem to checks for presence of html tags and entities, but I don't know why that is necessary at all.

Comment: I didn't write the code above. It is fully functional. It first searches for match between typed words and list of autocomplete words. And then it replaces "iPod Nano" to "<strong>iPod</strong> Nano" for example if you typed 'ipod' on the search bar.

Comment: Would you please provide a jsFiddle? (I know the edge cases where your code does not work, it works for normal cases of alphabet and digits, but you will get weird stuff once special characters come in).

Comment: I wouldn't know how to create jsFiddle for this, but I would appreciate it if you could go to http://sookei.com/aaa/ and type "ipo" and "ipod" and "nano"

Comment: There is not enough data to test. If your data ever contain `()[]*.+?|\^$`, your highlight function will fail.

Comment: I solved it by adding trim. Thank you for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Just added trim to prevent the trailing whitespace being highlighted.

```
highlight: function(value, term) {
return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + trim(term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1")) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

},